# NullPointerException on intent when accessing Camera Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to call the Camera app twice as described here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics
Now when I was using this without creating a temp file this worked and I was able to call the camera twice but after adding the temp file I am only able to take one file before crashing. it is very frustrating because I can see that it is returning a full size image before crashing.

I have tried doing a second .putExtras() before the get but that is not working. I have also tried assert not null, same results.

```java
private void takePictureAndUpload() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.provider",
                        photoFile);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                        , REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
            count++;
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            assert imageBitmap != null;
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            final byte[] imageData = stream.toByteArray();

            setuId(user);
            final String path = "posts/" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpg";

            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
            final StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child(path);


            UploadTask uploadTask = imageRef.putBytes(imageData);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    String ex = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    imageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUrl)
                        {
                            final String url = downloadUrl.toString();//do something with downloadurl
                            data.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, url);
                            addPhotoUrlToDatabase(post.getImageUrl_1(), post.getImageUrl_2(), path);

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

This should open the camera take a picture then after accepting the first picture it should reopen camera for a second picture. However so far all it does is open camera, take a picture then when I hit accept it crashes with a nullPointerException.

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android, PID: 21689
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.android/com.example.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4491)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1752)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:257)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7547)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4487)
```

**Edit**

This is the guide that I am following:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath

Comment: David House please add more details about the crash error from logcat

Comment: for me should be store temp uri for capture image, then after finish upload all together

Comment: Iqbal could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your intent is `null`, right?

Comment: Yes it is I see that this is an issue when creating file before passing to onActivityResult but I dont know how else to create a full size image and send that image to firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/37628687/10941659. It is not made clear on the android developer training site, but when you want to get a full size image you don't use the intent that you pass to onActivityResult. You need to use the path that you generate for your image, for example:

```java
private void takePictureAndUpload() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.provider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
            count++;
            Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
            try {
                imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),photoURI);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            final byte[] imageData = stream.toByteArray();

            setuId(user);
            final String path = "posts/" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpg";

            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
            final StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child(path);

            UploadTask uploadTask = imageRef.putBytes(imageData);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    String ex = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    imageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUrl)
                        {
                            final String url = downloadUrl.toString();//do something with downloadurl
                             addPhotoUrlToDatabase(post.getImageUrl_1(), post.getImageUrl_2(), path);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your activity result like this as using the same named parameters are confusing.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          }
```

Your Bundle seems like it's null.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, what you have does not look different from what I have.

Comment: You are passing two int parameters with the same name. Then you are calling that parameter and check if it's equal to something. Error prone and can lead into bugs that are hard to detect. Avoid naming that variables and parameters that way.

Comment: My parameters are named just as you have above - requestCode and resultCode, they are not the same.